# Get current date but SET time UNIX

Tags: php

Is it possible to get the current date, but set the time to 23:59 in UNIX?

I have been using the following, but this gives the current date and time.

```
$date = date('U');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example:

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime('2001-01-01');

    $date->setTime(23, 59);
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

    $date->setTime(23, 59, 00);
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
?>
```

the above code is from the official [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php)

**EDIT**

to output the UNIX timestamp simple use:

```
$date->setTime(23, 59, 00);
echo $date->format('U') . "\n";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but I need to output a UNIX timestamp for the days date but with the time set as 23:59. Your example doesn't output a timestamp.

Comment: @ccdavies It's not that hard. Just do `$date->format('U')` to output it in unix format.

Comment: @ccdavies I have updated my answer to include the Unix timestamp format. May I ask you to please upvote and mark the answer as accepted, so that future visitors can solve their issue faster? Thanks!

Comment: @N.Ivanov No green tick grabbing. The question was only asked recently and the OP is well within his rights to wait for possible better anwers!

Answer (score 0):

The php documentation contains all you need to know about this http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$time = date("H:i");
```

The code above should give you the 24 hour time for hh:mm.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to output a UNIX timestamp for the days date but with the time set as 23:59.

Answer (score 0):

You have to concate your time with the current data using date function. You can do something like this..

echo "Today is " . date("Y-m-d") . " 23:59";

Comment: Thank you, but I need to output a UNIX timestamp for the days date but with the time set as 23:59. Your example doesn't output a timestamp.

Comment: Ok so you can use strtotime function like below

$unixtimestame =  strtotime(date("Y-m-d") . " 23:59");
echo $unixtimestame; // it will give you unix time stamp..
echo date("Y-m-d h:i", $dd);  /// It will return your actual date..

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
echo date("U", mktime(23, 59, 0, date('n'), date('j'), date('Y')));
```

[Proof](https://ideone.com/b2eHgz).

Comment: Thank you. An error is output: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given

Comment: @ccdavies Updated.